# Swift: print array values sort by added

Tags: swift

My code :

```
internal static var myList = [Int: String]()

let data = "1:Tea#12:Food#2:Milk#7:Juice#4:Coffee"
let array = data.components(separatedBy: "#")
for value in array {
    let val = value.components(separatedBy: ":")
    myList[Int(val[0])!] = "\(val[1])"
}
```

Now print array :

```
var j = 0
for sort in myList {
    print("\(sort.value) (+\(sort.key))")
}
```

Output :

```
Tea
Milk
Coffee
Juice
Food
```

But i want print by added to array :

```
Tea
Food
Milk
Juice
Coffee
```

My array print values by key, but i want print by added to array

Comment: Is `myList` an array or a dictionary?

Comment: @Carpsen90 please check my question again

Comment: It's a dictionary! and dictionaries are unordered collections

Comment: @Carpsen90 ok. how can I converted to array ? or create array at first ?

Comment: Start with an array if the order in which they are created matters

Comment: @Carpsen90 i search `create array in swift` and give result `myList = [Int: String]()` again. can you send me how to create array in swift ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct

```
struct Item {
    let added : Int
    let index : Int
    let name : String
}
```

and map the array of the string components to instances of that struct

```
var myList = [Item]()

let data = "1:Tea#12:Food#2:Milk#7:Juice#4:Coffee"
for (index, element) in data.components(separatedBy: "#").enumerated() {
    let val = element.components(separatedBy: ":")
    myList.append(Item(added: index, index: Int(val[0])!, name: val[1]))
}
print(myList)
```